# Insert multiple values with duplicate key and different updates

Tags: mysql

I'm able to update my table when mykey (primary key) exists, or insert when mykey does not exist, with this query:

```
INSERT INTO customers (id, customer_id, page_id, mykey, hits) 
 VALUES 
(NULL, 1, 1, 23, 49) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+49;
```

Works fine. 
Now I can't figure out how to add multiple values in one query.
What I want is this:

```
INSERT INTO customers (id, customer_id, page_id, mykey, hits) 
 VALUES 
(NULL, 1, 1, 23, 49) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+49,
(NULL, 2, 2, 56, 11) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+11,
(NULL, 3, 3, 81, 14) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+14;
```

But that doesn't work.
Is it possible to insert or update multiple values like this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO customers (id, customer_id, page_id, mykey, hits) 
 VALUES 
(NULL, 1, 1, 23, 49),
(NULL, 2, 2, 56, 11),
(NULL, 3, 3, 81, 14)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+VALUES(hits);
```

Comment: Minor syntax error, missing commas after the first two sets of values.

Answer (score 0):

Do the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE once at the end:

```
INSERT INTO customers (id, customer_id, page_id, mykey, hits) 
 VALUES 
(NULL, 1, 1, 23, 49),
(NULL, 2, 2, 56, 11),
(NULL, 3, 3, 81, 14) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+VALUES(hits);
```

Comment: Doens't work, because all update rows would have hits=hits+14.

Comment: @Aiken Thanks, missed that!